# statement.executeQuery returning resultset with no rows

Tags: java, sql, database, oracle, jdbc

My problem is that when I fire a query directly into Oracle, it returns me the rows with proper data. But when I try to fire the same query via Statement, its fetching me a resultset with no rows.

My code is as follows :

```
public void sendSMStoMobile() {
        if (smsGatewayStatus.equals("STOPPED")) {
            stringBuilder.append("The control is returning" + "\n");
            jTextArea1.setText(stringBuilder.toString());
            return;
        }

        DBCP dbcp = DBCP.getInstance(database_url, username, password);
        Connection connection = null;
        Statement statement = null;
        try {
            connection = dbcp.getConnection();
            statement = connection.createStatement();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Send_SMS_Form.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            System.out.println("Message : " + ex.getMessage());
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Send_SMS_Form.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            System.out.println("Message : " + ex.getMessage());
        }

        ResultSet resultSet = null;

        try {
            sql = new StringBuffer();
            sql.append("SELECT SMS_ID, MOBILE_NO, SMS_CONTENT ");
            sql.append("FROM SMSDATA.SMS_DATA ");
            //sql.append("WHERE SENT_STATUS = 'N' AND Message_Code IN('LOANREPAY') " );
            //sql.append("WHERE SENT_STATUS = 'N' AND Message_Code IN('SPECIAL') " );
            sql.append("WHERE SENT_STATUS = 'N' ");
            //sql.append("WHERE tranum <= (select max(tranum) -25 from smsgtway.sms_all_tran where SENT_STATUS = 'N' AND Message_Code IN('MEMDEP','MEMGRANT','SAMGRANT'))  and SENT_STATUS = 'N' AND Message_Code IN('MEMDEP','MEMGRANT','SAMGRANT') " );
            sql.append("ORDER BY SMS_ID desc ");
            // sql.append("ORDER BY SENT_TIMSTAMP " );

            //  For Test
            //sql.append("SELECT  customer_Code,MOBILE_NO, SMS_CONTENT,SMS_ID " );
            //sql.append("FROM MB_SMS_DTL ");
            //sql.append("WHERE SENT_STATUS = 'N' ");
            //sql.append("ORDER BY SMS_ID " );
            // End Test
            resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql.toString());

            System.out.println("Code comes here");
            /*   if(!resultSet.next()){ 
             stringBuilder.append("No Data Found" +"\n");
             jTextArea1.setText(stringBuilder.toString());
             } */


            if (!resultSet.next()) {
                System.out.println("no data");
            } else {

                System.out.println("Data Found...");
                do {
                    //statement(s)
                } while (resultSet.next());
            }
            while (resultSet.next()) {

                System.out.println("Data Found...");
                String smsId = resultSet.getString(1);
                String destMobileNo = resultSet.getString(2);
                String message = resultSet.getString(3);
                OutboundMessage sms = new OutboundMessage(destMobileNo, message);

                System.out.println("Code comes here" + smsId);
                //System.out.println("sms = " + sms);
                try {
                    Service.getInstance().sendMessage(sms);
                } catch (TimeoutException timeoutException) {
                    System.out.println("1");
                    stringBuilder.append("Exception : " + timeoutException.getMessage() + "\n");
                    jTextArea1.setText(stringBuilder.toString());
                } catch (GatewayException gatewayException) {
                    System.out.println("2");
                    stringBuilder.append("Exception : " + gatewayException.getMessage() + "\n");
                    jTextArea1.setText(stringBuilder.toString());
                } catch (IOException iOException) {
                    System.out.println("3");
                    stringBuilder.append("Exception : " + iOException.getMessage() + "\n");
                    jTextArea1.setText(stringBuilder.toString());
                } catch (InterruptedException interruptedException) {
                    System.out.println("4");
                    stringBuilder.append("Exception : " + interruptedException.getMessage() + "\n");
                    jTextArea1.setText(stringBuilder.toString());
                } catch (java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException siobe) {
                    System.out.println("5");
                    stringBuilder.append("Exception : " + siobe.getMessage() + "\n");
                    jTextArea1.setText(stringBuilder.toString());
                }

                //Update Table After Send Message
                String updateQuery = "UPDATE SMSDATA.SMS_DATA SET SENT_STATUS = 'Y', SENT_DATE = sysdate WHERE SMS_ID = " + smsId;
                //String updateQuery = "UPDATE MB_SMS_DTL SET SENT_STATUS = 'Y' WHERE SMS_ID = " + tranNumber ;

                //System.out.println("Update Query: " + updateQuery);
                if (i < 10) {
                    System.out.print(smsId + ": Y, ");
                }
                if (i == 10) {
                    System.out.print(smsId + ": Y, " + "\n");
                    i = 0;
                }
                statement.executeUpdate(updateQuery);
                connection.commit();
                i = i + 1;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Message: " + e.getMessage());
            System.out.println("Cause: " + e.getCause());
            stringBuilder.append("Message: " + e.getMessage() + "\n");
            stringBuilder.append("Cause: " + e.getCause() + "\n");
            jTextArea1.setText(stringBuilder.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (resultSet != null) {
                try {
                    resultSet.close();
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Send_SMS_Form.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
            if (statement != null) {
                try {
                    statement.close();
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Send_SMS_Form.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
            dbcp.releaseConnection(connection);
            //Service.getInstance().stopService();
        }
    }
```

When I call this function , "no data" is printed in Console . The sql is correct . When I run the sql in Toad , I have found 2 rows .

Please help me .

Comment: Question is edited

Comment: There is no way to answer this: for all we know there is simply no data that satisfies the conditions of the query.

Comment: Have you tried another (simply) query to test the connection?

Comment: Your use of `StringBuffer` is distressing for 3 reasons. 1) This is a compile-time constant `String` - the compiler would have replaced `+` at compile time, you have actually make this situation worse. 2) `StringBuffer` is the `synchornized` variant of `StringBuilder` and shouldn't be used unless required. 3) Concatenating SQL queries a runtime is genenrally a bad idea as it encourages code vulnerable to SQL injection - I don't see evidence of that here, but be **very** wary.

Comment: You are iterating your resultSet twice.

Comment: How you are maintaining cursor..??

Comment: You're right, @Sanjeev; this does seem to be the problem. If the OP has a supported `ResultSet` it could be rewound.

Comment: Good catch @Sanjeev, that could be a issue as it was already called with DO block .

Comment: @BoristheSpider are  you pointing Updatequery in your 3rd point..??, I think appending string will be fine, if it appended before execution of any sql statement. 

And Is this Hack can be overcome by PreparedStatement ..??

Comment: @Simmant I am pointing to both `sql` and `updateQuery`. Both are anathema in modern Java. It is **never** okay to build a SQL query with concatenation; and building one that sticks in parameters of any kind is a disciplinary offence at many companies. You are correct that `PreparedStatement` should be used for all SQL interaction.

Comment: If you post an [MCVE]  (Minimal is a key here) which reproduce the problem, it will help you get better help (and most probably will help you find it yourself).

Comment: Do you have uncommitted inserts/updates in your Toad session, perhaps? (Agree the two iterations over `resultSet` are a problem, but the 'no data' message is too early for that to be the immediate issue that produces that message).

Comment: there is no way your second `while` statement condition becomes successful as you already iterated through the result set in first  `while` statement

Comment: Are you sure the TOAD session and code JDBC connection are for the same Oracle instance and schema? Second - as already mentioned - are you sure the TOAD does not have a transation open? Could you reconnect the TOAD session to be sure?

Comment: First things first you should always add a catch for a general excpetion. Try before executing the SELECT printing the sql.toString() to see what it prints

Comment: @IoannaKatsanou I think you mean the exact opposite: you should **never** `catch(Exception e)` because you have no idea what you are catching or how to handle it. In fact, most static code analysis tools will complain loudly if you try.